# Какая функция используется в С++ для вывода количества чисел?

Tags: c++builder, c++

Допустим, есть числа 156, 13, 42, 12, 123, и мне нужно их количество - 5.

Какую функцию использовать?

```
strlen(int_a);
или
int_a.length();
```

Comment: 1. Если вы пишете на С++, а не на Си, то правильнее будет использовать length().

2. Ни одна из этих функций не решит вашу задачу, впрочем как и другие встроенные функции. Вам придется писать свою собственную функцию, которая будет разбирать строку и считать количество чисел.

Comment: @bellator001, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Зависит от того, как эти числа организованны.

Если это массив, размер которого известен на этапе компиляции:

`int a[]={156, 13, 42, 12, 123};`

можно использовать выражение `sizeof a / sizeof a[0]`.

Если они в стандартном контейнере вроде `std::vector<int>`, то есть функция-член `size()`.

Comment: Судя по тому, что автор спрашивает про функции strlen и String.lenght(), это, скорее всего, входная строка. Хотя да, лучше уточнить момент, в каком виде хранятся данные.

Answer (score 0):

[[[[@bellator001](/users/27503/bellator001)](/users/27503/bellator001)](/users/27503/bellator001)](/users/27503/bellator001), Вам правильно сказали, что одной библиотечной функции нет. В зависимости от формата данных в строке придется использовать разные функции.

```
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ cat c.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char *
strtos (char **p, const char *delim)
{
  char *word = 0;

  if (*((*p) += strspn(*p, delim))) {
    word = *p;
    (*p) += strcspn(*p, delim);
  }

  return word;
}

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  int rc = 1, n = 0, d;
  if (av[1]) {
    if (isdigit(av[1][0])) {
      FILE *f = fmemopen(av[1], strlen(av[1]), "r");

      while (fscanf(f, "%d", &d) == 1)
        n++;

      rc = !feof(f);
      fclose(f);
    } else {
      char *w, *ep = av[1];
      int err = 0, l;

      while (w = strtos(&ep, " ,")) {
        char *p, buf[(l = ep - w) + 1];
        strncpy(buf, w, l);
        buf[l] = 0;
        strtol(buf, &p, 10);
        if (!*p)
          n++;
        else
          err++;
      }
      rc = err > 0;
    }
    printf ("%d numbers (%s)\n", n, rc ? "Err" : "OK");
  }

  return rc;
}
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ g++ c.c
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ ./a.out ' 1, 2, 33, 4, 616'
5 numbers (OK)
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ ./a.out '1, 2, 33, 4, 616'
1 numbers (Err)
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ ./a.out ' 1 2 33'
3 numbers (OK)
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ ./a.out '1 2 33'
3 numbers (OK)
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$
```

Я намерено не писал комментарии в этой программе, но привел ее вывод для разных входных данных, чтобы несколько упростить [[[[@bellator001](/users/27503/bellator001)](/users/27503/bellator001)](/users/27503/bellator001)](/users/27503/bellator001) процесс разбора.

Comment: Не очень понятный код, например, непонятно, почему во втором примере ошибка. Кроме того, использованы однобуквенные переменные и  нестандартная функция `fmemopen`.

Comment: @Im ieee, ошибка во втором примере, как несложно заметить, почитав код, возникает из-за fscanf() для чтения чисел.

Собственно, `if (isdigit...` и управляет выбором метода их чтения.

Что же касается нестандартности `fmemopen` -- да,  любителям винды не повезло...

--

Таким образом выбор очевиден -- пользуйте `strtos()` (или свой аналог).

Answer (score 0):

Если формат именно такой - "156, 13, 42, 12, 123", то подсчитать количество запятых и увеличить на единицу.